# Looking for statements true in all finite models which are false in infinite models

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, model-theory

I want to know about:

1. Statements which are tautological in all finite models but false in some infinite model.
2. Statements which are tautological in all infinite models, but false in some finite model.

One example of 1 is "$G$ is a DAG implies $G$ has a sink". Another example of 1 is "there are an even number of odd degree vertices in $G$".

Comment: In what *language*? Models of what *theory*?

Comment: The language of graphs, first order theory of graphs. I mean I'm interested in other things but for concreteness that works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy one for 2: "$\exists x\exists y(x\not=y)$." This is true in exactly those structures which have at least two elements, hence true in any infinite structure; at the same time, it is not true in a one-element structure.

For 1, you've already found some examples. My favorite, though, is a piece of hard algebra. The language here is the language of rings, and the sentence says $$(*)\quad\mbox{If this is a division ring, then it is commutative.}$$ (That is, it says [division ring axioms]$\implies$[commutativity]. It's tedious, but simple, to express it formally in first-order logic.) Clearly $(*)$ is false in some infinite structure (say, [the quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)); but surprisingly, it turns out that every finite division ring is commutative! This is a hard result - [Wedderburn's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem). The nice proofs I know of each use group cohomology.

Comment: You must have meant commutative ;)

Comment: @Max Hey now, I wasn't *wrong*, was I? :P Fixed, thanks!